# Flash / Actionscript: How to make overlapping sprite invisible

Tags: flash, actionscript, alpha, blend, filter

See image at http://reggino.kingsquare.nl/tmp/actionscriptProblem.jpg

Hi there,

I can't get my head around this one...

I'm having two sprites, where the intersection of these sprites has an alpha of 0. I tried all the blendmodes and filters, but none of them seems appropriate.

I've been puzzeling with extra layers on top of these three, masking each other etc, but that becomes a mess and makes it difficult to maintain (the text has to be dragged etc.... ). Does any of you guru's have a suggestion how to overcome this problem? There should be an easier way i think...?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The sprites are siblings indeed, but at the overlapping areas you can 'see through them'. The image provided illustrates this behaviour.

[edit]
I just managed to achieve the desired result by generating a custom new bitmap! See [this blogpost](http://kingsquare.nl/blog/07-12-2009/13451001/Flash-Actionscript-custom-alpha-blending-Class-NandAlphaBlender).

Answer (score 0):

How is the `alpha` of the intersection becoming zero?

If sprite1 (the text) and sprite2 (the strip) are siblings, you can addChild them in such a way that strip is at a higher position than text in the parent's display list by calling `addChild(text);` before calling `addChild(strip);` (or by calling `addChildAt(text, 0);`) - This way, the strip will be on top of the text and cover it if there is an overlap.